# how to use Wildcard with `WHERE IN(' ')` statment

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, sql-in

I have a `WHERE IN ('')` statement, if nothing is entered, how do I select ALL?

Comment: or param is null

Comment: You can handle it by using variables. In which language you are using this query ?

Comment: @RyanJacques catch-all queries result in bad execution plans. *Don't* use that condition if you don't need to. Either execute a *different* query, or use an `IF` in your stored procedure to pick the correct query. Better options are to use an ORM on the client to write just the query you need to execute.

Comment: @RyanJacques why do you want to write a catch-all in the first place?

Comment: Querying from Excel VBA - multiple selection boxes i.e. Product, Region, Status. Im using IN as i may have multiple products and multiple regions, but no status?

Answer (score 2):

Depend on database you are working. But you can do something like this:

```
-- SQLServer
DECLARE @in varchar(20) = ''
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE (@in = '' or <field> IN (''))

-- OR
IF @in = '' 
    SELECT * FROM <table>
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <field> IN ('')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all values, if there is no value for a variable, then just use `ISNULL` function( **will have an index scan**):

`WHERE  yourField IN (ISNULL(@yourNullVariable, yourField))`

Let me show an example:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    FooDate DATETIME,
    FooBar VARCHAR(50) 
)

INSERT INTO @table
(
    FooDate,
    FooBar
)
VALUES
(   GETDATE(), -- FooDate - datetime
    'A'         -- FooBar - varchar(50)
    )
, ('2019-02-18', 'AA')
, ('2019-01-18', 'B')
, ('2019-01-18', 'BB')

DECLARE @fooVariable VARCHAR(50) = NULL
SELECT * FROM @table tbl
WHERE  tbl.FooBar = ISNULL(@fooVariable, tbl.FooBar)
```

OUTPUT:

```
FooDate                    FooBar
2019-02-18 16:37:20.920      A
2019-02-18 00:00:00.000      AA
2019-01-18 00:00:00.000      B
2019-01-18 00:00:00.000      BB
```

Or use dynamic SQL( **will have an index seek**):

```
DECLARE @fooVariable VARCHAR(50) = NULL
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max), @where NVARCHAR(255);

SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM Yourtable tbl'
IF @fooVariable IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN 
        SET @where = ' tbl.FooBar = ' + @fooVariable
        SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, @where)
    END


EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: This will prevent the use of indexes and force a full table scan

Comment: It also doesn't make sense in the context of `where in ()` because `@fooVariable` may only contain one value, at which point you can use `where =`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the right comment.Yeah, you are right. Is it possible to have an index seek without using `IF` and `ELSE` statements and dynamic SQL?